# How to call an external javascript function on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following jquery/ajax code in a php file and onUploadComplete I'd like to call the function totalprice() which is located in an external js file (the js file is already loaded).

Right now the console throws the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: totalprice is not defined

How do I define the function totalprice() in this case?

PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'              : true,
        'height'            : 30,
        'width'             : 180,
        'multi'             : false,
        'removeCompleted'   : true,
        'fileSizeLimit'     : 6000,
        'buttonText'        : 'Choose your image',
        'formData'          : {
            'timestamp'     : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'         : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'queueID'          : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'     : '/inc/conf_user_uploader/uploader.php',
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
             console.log(data);
            $('.pane').load('/conf_upload_image.php');
            $('.label-bodyprintImage').html('Custom image');
            $('.price-bodyprintImage').html( $('input:[name=customImagePrice]').val() );
            totalprice();
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

JS file:

```
function totalprice() {

var sum = 0;

sum =   Number($('.price-bodyImage').text()) 
        + Number($('.price-waistbandImage').text())
        + Number($('.price-collarImage').text())   
        + Number($('.price-standupcollarImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-leftsleeveImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-leftsleevecuffImage').text()) 
        + Number($('.price-rightsleeveImage').text())   
        + Number($('.price-rightsleevecuffImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-hoodImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-bodyprintImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-leftsleeveprintImage').text())  
        + Number($('.price-rightsleeveprintImag').text())                   
        ;

$('.price-totalprice').html(sum);

}
```

Comment: your total price function js file included before your ajax function ?

Comment: It sounds like the totalprice JS file isn't being included for some reason - try putting `console.log('totalprice loaded');` at the start of the file to verify that.
Assuming that's not the problem, there's nothing physically wrong with the code you've posted - it works, so you'll need to post a link or enough detail for us to replicate the code not working.

Comment: try wrapping the uploadifive code inside a    $(document).ready(function(){/* Code here */}); Perhaps the js files loading are not sequential